# How do you utilize an activity's layout in a non activity class?

Tags: android, layout, view, android-resources, layout-inflater

so in a non activity class I'm trying to use another activity's layout and pass it down into a couple methods. I first inflated the layout (turned into a view) and passed it down into a couple methods, eventually I get an error such as:

Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f09002c type #0x12 is not valid.

Well, before going further here is my code.

```
LayoutInflater l = (LayoutInflater) activity.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

      //Get our views
        View userCard = l.inflate(R.layout.user_card, null, false);

      arrayAdapter2 = new GlobalArrayAdapter<String>(context, userCard);
```

I made my own custom arrayAdapter, and in there I have:

```
        public GlobalArrayAdapter(Context context, View userCard)
        {
             mContext = context;
             mResource = mDropDownResource = userCard.getId();

        }
```

Then finally, in my last method where I have the error it is.

```
 private View createViewFromResource(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent, int resource)
    {
        mResource = resource;
        View view;
        if (convertView == null) {
            view = mInflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);//THIS IS WHERE I GET AN ERROR!!!
        } else {
            view = convertView;
            //...and so on
        }
```

So, I'm not sure if I inflated correctly and if I did, not sure if I converted that view back into an int resource so that I can use it in methods that require an integer. Hopefully you guys can assist!

Comment: `View.getId()` isn't the same as the resourceId used to inflate from.. .why not just pass down the `R.layout.???` value directly?

Comment: @Buddy I thought about that, but how can I pass down a layout in a non activity class? It won't be able to find the layout, with a "setContentView(R.layout...); like in activity classes

Comment: What *exactly* are you trying to achieve doing this? Maybe there's a better way

Comment: @codeMagic so it is really a lot to explain. But, im using someone else's library to make swipeable cards (like tinder). And to eventually make a card, you have to use the arrayadapter class, which takes in a layout. So when i implement this stuff in an activity it works fine. But, I want to put a lot of code into a non activity global class that has an arrayadapter that can be accessed from any class within my project. So I want to make cards in a non activity class and to do that it requires an arrayadapter which requires a layout

Comment: You just need the `context` to inflate the view in your so called _non activity_ class (or better call it the adapter class). You should used [LayoutInflater](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html) to inflate views.

Comment: @Antrromet can you give an example of how to do that exactly?